# Next.JS dynamic meta tags

Tags: javascript, next.js, meta-tags

I added some dynamic meta tags for a page in my next.js application.

```js
import CoinTossPage from '@/views/CoinTossPage';
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import Head from 'next/head';
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';
import axios from 'axios';

function CoinTossComponent() {
  const router = useRouter();
  const { id } = router.query;
  const [poolData, setPoolData] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (id) {
      fetchPoolData();
    }
  }, [id]);

  // fetch pool data from API using pool id
  const fetchPoolData = async () => {
    try {
      let config = {
        method: 'get',
        url: `${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_BASE_URL}/api/v1/gambling/coin-flip/pool/${id}`,
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_KEY}`,
        },
      };
      const response = await axios(config);
      if (response.status === 200) {
        const payload = response.data.payload;
        if (payload) {
          setPoolData(payload);
        } else {
          setPoolData(null);
        }
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('ERROR while fetching active pools from API ', error);
    }
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Head>
        <meta property="og:title" content={poolData?.tokenSymbol} />
        <meta property="og:image" content={poolData?.imageUrl} />
      </Head>
      <CoinTossPage />
    </>
  );
}

export default CoinTossComponent;
```

This is how it is added and, this is how it appear when I look it on page inspect.

[image]

**It's clearly showing the dynamic content in meta tags. But when I share the page link, this image is not appearing.**

What is the issue?

I tried reading their documentation https://nextjs.org/learn/seo/rendering-and-ranking/metadata and added meta tags according to it.

Comment: Please read [ask], in particular the part about not posting pictures of code.

Comment: You also need to provide a real [mcve]. Relevent information missing from your question includes: (a) What the HTML (not the parsed DOM) looks like and (b) How many bytes into the document the `<meta` elements begin.

Comment: Is your site server-side rendered?

Comment: @MattPeng - hence (a) in my previous comment (even if it is, the effect hook might mean *that part* isn't rendered in time).

Comment: @KavinduMadushanka It's possible that the social media platform you're sharing the link on is not able to access the dynamic meta tags on your page. This can happen if the platform's crawler is not able to execute JavaScript or if there are other issues with the way the meta tags are set up.

Comment: @KavinduMadushanka if you use server side render we can  use the getServerSideProps function to fetch the poolData and pass it as a prop to the CoinTossComponent. This will ensure that the meta tags are rendered on the server side and can be accessed by social media crawlers.

Comment: Yes! The image appeared when sharing the link after adding SSR to that page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to everyone who helped me with the above issue. This is the corrected code

```js
import CoinTossPage from '@/views/CoinTossPage';
import React from 'react';
import Head from 'next/head';
import axios from 'axios';

function CoinTossComponent({poolData}) {
  return (
    <>
      <Head>
        <meta property="og:title" content={poolData?.tokenSymbol} />
        <meta property="og:image" content={poolData?.imageUrl} />
      </Head>
      <CoinTossPage />
    </>
  );
}

export async function getServerSideProps(context) {

  const { id } = context.query; // Access the route parameter

  let config = {
    method: 'get',
    url: `${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_BASE_URL}/api/v1/gambling/coin-flip/pool/${id}`,
    headers: {
      Authorization: `Bearer ${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_KEY}`,
    },
  };
  const response = await axios(config);
  const poolData = response.data.payload;

  // Return the data as props
  return {
    props: {
      poolData,
    },
  };
}

export default CoinTossComponent;
```

Answer (score 0):

In NextJS, some parts of the HTML are rendered on the client (e.g. Google Chrome) and some other parts are rendered on the frontend server. If the metadata consumers don't see the metadata that you see on the client, then it's possible that the following happened:

- The metadata consumer (e.g. Twitter) sends a request to the frontend server.
- The frontend server returns some starting resources that don't require blocking. If the elements in the `<Head>` require some client-side processing, then the frontend server will not return the data in it and will just return a minimal HTML that tells the client how to keep loading it until it reaches the intended state.
- The metadata consumer reads the minimal `<Head>`.
- The client reconciles the state and gets all the data that's needed to populate the full `<Head>`.

This problem can be solved by fetching the data that's needed for the `<Head>` in the server. That can be done using [getStaticProps](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/data-fetching/get-static-props) or using [getServerSideProps](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/data-fetching/get-server-side-props).